# Show that any subset of $(\mathbb{N},d)$ is open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that any subset of $(\mathbb{N},d)$ is open and closed, where $$d(m,n) = \frac{|m-n|}{1+|m-n|}$$

my attempt:

let $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ then for any $x \in A$ we have that $B(x,1/3) = \{x\} \subset A$ Hence $A$ is open. (here $B(x,1/3)$ is the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $1/3$). I am struggling to show that $A$ is also closed.

Comment: You showed that any subset is open. In particular, for a fixed $A$, the complement of $A$ is also open. Hence $A$ is closed.

Comment: @ThibautDumont of course! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to show that any singleton is open. Indeed, if this is the case, every subset is a union of singletons, so it is open. And if every subset is open, every subset is also closed.

Your proof is good to show that $B(x,1/3)=\{x\}$, which precisely says $\{x\}$ is open.

Indeed
$$
\frac{|x-n|}{1+|x-n|}<\frac{1}{3}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
3|x-n|<1+|x-n|
$$
or
$$
|x-n|<\frac{1}{2}
$$
If $n\ne x$, of course $|x-n|\ge1$ (when $x,n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. You say this is equivalent to showing every singleton is open. I don't quite see how this is equivalent, could you expand on that please?

Comment: @DH. If every subset is open, every singleton, in particular, is. If every singleton is open, then any subset is open, because any set is the union of singletons and unions of open sets are open. Saying that every subset is open is the same as saying that every subset is closed, because closed sets are the complements of open sets.

Answer (score 3):

Take a sequence $a_n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=x\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $B(x,1/3)=\{x\}$ there exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ $a_n\in B(x,1/3)=\{x\}$, so the sequence $a_n$ is eventually constant iguals to $x$ and then $x\in A$ which means that $A$ is closed.